# Как выводить в логи при старте, какие урлы были замаппены

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Используется Spring framework. Все конфигурации сделаны с помощью кода. Можно ли как то при старте приложения, когда оно разворачивается в томкете, выводить в лог, какие урлы были созданы?

Comment: У вас и так должен маппинг выводиться в консоль

Comment: но он не выводится

Comment: Покажите полный лог старта